# Insertar datos a MySQL mediante Python y Flask

Tags: mysql, python, flask

Estoy tratando de insertar datos a MySQL mediante Python y Flask, estos datos los obtengo de un formulario, pero me arroja este error: [image]

Mi código fuente lo tengo de esta manera:

```
@app.route('/add', methods=['POST'])
def add_user():
    try:        
      _name = request.form['inputName']
      _password = request.form['inputPassword']

      if _name and _email and _password and request.method == 'POST':

        sql = "INSERT INTO usuarios(nombre_user, contrasena_user) VALUES(%s, %s)"
        data = (_name,_password,)
        conexion=mysql.connect()
        cursor=conexion.cursor()
        cursor.execute(sql,data)
        conexion.commit()
        return redirect('/')    
    else:
        return 'Error al agregar usuario'
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
finally:
    cursor.close() 
    conexion.close()
```

Alguien puede decirme que es lo que tengo mal

Comment: debes especificarle la conexion hay no haces nada...  `conexion 
 =mysql.connector.connect(
 database='python_db',
  host="localhost",
  user="username",
  passwd="password"
)`

Comment: la variable `_email` no existe por lo tanto te salta una excepción, esa excepción es capturada por el `except Exception as e:` y despues ejecuta el `finally:` para cerrar la conexión pero como nunca entró al `if` la variable `cursor` nunca fue creada.